# how to compare the first three octets of two Ip adresses contained in two PhP variables

Tags: php

I have two php variables which contains two ipv4 addresses, i need to compare the first three octets and return true if they match, and false if they don't. Help for writing a block of code is appreciated.

```
<?php
include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
mysql_connect("173.86.45,9","abcd","1236");
mysql_select_db("vc");
$pl=mysql_query("SELECT stat_ip from Hasoffers");
$count=mysql_num_rows($pl);


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pl))
{
$stat_ip=$row['stat_ip'];
echo sec($stat_ip)."<br>";
}

function sec($stat_ip)
{
  $result = mysql_query("select stat_ip from Hasoffers where stat_ip ='".$stat_ip."'");



                  if(condition to check if the octets match)
                {
                  //i need to write the condition if within the table Hasoffers, there are more than 2 'stat_ip'(column) values, having the same 3 octets.
                   printf("true");

                   }

               else
              {
                printf("false, octets don't match");


              }
                 return $num_rows;
}



?>
```

Comment: show *variables which contains two ipv4 addresses* to get a quick help

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have a table Hasoffers, containing a column stat_ip( containing ip addresses). i need to find within the same column, if there are duplicate ip adresses( by comparing the first three octets only).

Comment: So if I understand right, you want a list of IP's with the same first 3 octets right?

Comment: @NikolayGanovski, yes right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to implement this is:

```
$ip1 = '192.168.0.1';
$ip2 = '192.168.0.2';

$ip1 = explode('.', $ip1);
$ip2 = explode('.', $ip2);
if ($ip1[0]==$ip2[0] && $ip1[1]==$ip2[1] && $ip1[2]==$ip2[2]) {
    //your code here
}
```

EDIT: 
Try to replace your sec() function with this one(read the comments),and edit it.

```
function sec($stat_ip)
{
$octets = explode('.', $stat_ip);
$first_three = $octets[0].'.'.$octets[1].'.'.$octets[2].'.'; //this looks like 192.168.0.
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT stat_ip from Hasoffers where stat_ip LIKE '".$first_three."%'"); //this gives you all ip's starting with the current ip
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)>1) 
  {
    //we have more than one ip starting with current ip
    //do something here
  }
  else
  {
    //result returns 1 or 0 rows, no matching ip's
  }
   //return $something;
}
```

Comment: Can you please refer the code, i've posted above. I need to compare the 3 octets of ip adrress contained in the same column named stat_ip, in table named Hasoffers.

Comment: The query you fetched in $result, will return ip's starting with $stat_ip, but i need to return values only starting with first three subnets. Where is $first_three being used in this. ? Can you help me with this.

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake. In the query instead of stat_ip should be first_three, check edited answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `strrpos` and `substr` functions:

```
$ip1 = '192.168.10.121';
$ip2 = '192.168.10.122';

// the position of the last octet separator
$last_dot_pos = strrpos($ip1, '.');
$is_matched = substr($ip1, 0, $last_dot_pos) == substr($ip2, 0, $last_dot_pos);

var_dump($is_matched);
```

The output:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    $ipOne = "192.168.1.1";
    $ipTwo = "192.168.1.2";

    $ipOneParts = explode(".", $ipOne);
    $ipTwoParts = explode(".", $ipTwo);

    if(($ipOneParts[0] == $ipTwoParts[0]) && 
       ($ipOneParts[1] == $ipTwoParts[1]) && 
       ($ipOneParts[2] == $ipTwoParts[2])){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

convert them into array using explode using "." and compare the first index of both array.